# How to get distinct values from an array of fetch API output

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I am trying to fetch the json data from an API and split its value and populate the value in my React project.The code for server API is as shown below:

```
const clone = require('clone')
const config = require('./config')

let db = {}

const defaultData = {
  categories: [
      {
        name: 'react',
        path: 'react'
      },
      {
        name: 'redux',
        path: 'redux'
      },
      {
        name: 'udacity',
        path: 'udacity'
      }
  ]
}

function getData (token) {
  //Each token has it's own copy of the DB. The token in this case is like an app id.
  let data = db[token]
  //This populates the default user data if there isn't any in the db.
  if (data == null) {
    data = db[token] = clone(defaultData)
  }
  return data
}

function getAll (token) {
  return new Promise((res) => {
    res(getData(token))
  })
}

module.exports = {
  getAll
}
```

And, I am trying to get the data from the above API with the code shown below:

**readableAPI.js**

```
const url = "http://localhost:3001/"

let token = localStorage.token
if (!token)
  token = localStorage.token = Math.random().toString(46).substr(-8)

const headers = {
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': token
}

export const getCategories = () =>
fetch('http://localhost:3001/categories', {headers})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
```

Then in my React component, I am trying to get the result of the API as shown below:

```
import * as readableAPI from './readableAPI.js'

class App extends Component {

componentDidMount() {
  readableAPI.getCategories().then((category) => 
  category.map( value => console.log(value.name)))
}

...

}
```

Now the problem I am facing is: in the above code in the componentDidMount() lifecycle method,I am able to fetch the json data with the code given below:

```
componentDidMount() {
    readableAPI.getCategories()
}
```

The above code gives the array of the 3 categories:

```
{categories: Array(3)}
   0: {name: "react", path: "react"}
   1: {name: "redux", path: "redux"}
   2: {name: "udacity", path: "udacity"}
```

But, if I try to map over the array and get the individual values using the below code,I get the output as undefined.

```
componentDidMount() {
      readableAPI.getCategories().then((category) => 
      category.map( value => console.log(value.name)))
    }
```

I want to get the values of each categories so I can use the name of the category available in the server and display it in my react component.Where am I going wrong.Can anyone please guide me with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning anything from the fetch:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3001/categories', {headers})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data)) // you should return the data (or promise) here
```

This is how you write the fetch (run it):

```js
var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
const getCategories = () =>
  fetch(root + '/posts/1', {
    method: 'GET'
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => console.log('inside the fetch - ', data))


getCategories().then((category) => {
  console.log('outside the fetch - ', category);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fetch/2.0.3/fetch.min.js"></script>
```

This is the fix (run it):

```js
var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
const getCategories = () =>
  fetch(root + '/posts/1', {
    method: 'GET'
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log('inside the fetch - ', data);
    // you must return the data!
    return data;
  })


getCategories().then((category) => {
  console.log('outside the fetch - ', category);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fetch/2.0.3/fetch.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So does it mean my code should look something like this: fetch('http://localhost:3001/categories', {headers})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => return data)

Comment: yes, you can omit the `return` in this case and just `.then(data => data)`

Comment: check my edit to the answer. i've included a running examples

Comment: I am able to get the result,but I am not able to fetch a distinct value from the array using the map function.For eg.only the first name of the category from the array.Can you please suggest how to proceed with that.

Comment: yeah,I am not able to get the desired output.I am facing some errors while executing the map function.

Comment: I tried something like this: readableAPI.getCategories().then(category => {
    if (category) {
        category.map(value => console.log(value))
    }
  })

Comment: But I get the following error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: category.map is not a function

Comment: Thats because you are geeting an object back from the fetch and not an array. Inside this object you got a key named `categories` which is the actual array. So you need to acees it this way `category.categories.map`

Comment: OMG,that worked.Thank you so much for the help.I had been struggling with this for hours.I am accepting your answer.Thanks a lot once again :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're accessing the object returned from `getCategories` correctly? It looks like your array is inside the `categories` key:

```
componentDidMount() {
    readableAPI.getCategories().then(result => 
    result.categories.map( category => console.log(category.name)))
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if I am doing it the right way.Can you please suggest how to proceed?

Comment: After you call `getCategories`, try logging the value of the response to make sure it's what you expect. It doesn't look like it's just an array as you said, it's an array inside a `categories` key.